# How to get direction between 2 longitude and latitude entered by user

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have two inputs which should accept longitude and latitude but I don't know exactly the format the user should enter correctly

```
 <div id="floating-panel">
<b>Start: </b>
  <input type="text" id="start" />

<b>End: </b>
      <input type="text" id="end" />

</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

<      java script for direction service
every time i insert latlng NOT_FOUND alret appear

```
<script>
    function initMap() {
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 7,
            center: { lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65 }
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        var onChangeHandler = function () {
            calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        };
        document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
        document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
    }

    function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        directionsService.route({
            origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
            destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        }, function (response, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            } else {
                window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyASxgrYPchqtEpQ0wm-XVHeud4Q-Flo90U&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using comma separated numbers like "40.7127837, -74.0059413" works for me.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/m64550xz/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {
      lat: 41.85,
      lng: -87.65
    }
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  var onChangeHandler = function() {
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
  };
  document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
  document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
    destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="floating-panel">
  <b>Start: </b>
  <input type="text" id="start" value="40.7127837, -74.0059413" />

  <b>End: </b>
  <input type="text" id="end" value="40.735657, -74.1723667" />

</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: What are the latitude and longitude you are entering that give you that error? Not all locations on the earth can be routed to by the directions service.